# How to execute a script after login with active directory for every user

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory

My script is called `configproxy.sh` and use `gsettings` command. I'm on ubuntu 22.04.

I put my script in  `/etc/profile.d/` and it seems to work only with local users. When I log myself with an active directory login nothing happens.

I tried to add this line in `/etc/pam.d/login`:

```
session optional pam_exec.so /bin/bash /etc/profile.d/configproxy.sh
```

but it doesn't seems to work either.

Please Help me!

**Edit**: When I open a terminal and execute `echo $0` I get `kwartz-sh`. Kwartz is a manager on the server. But there is a link from `kwartz-sh` to `bash`. To make this link I used the command:

```
ln -s /bin/bash /bin/kwartz-sh
```

Moreover, if I run my script in the terminal logged as an AD user it works.

For info here is the script `/etc/profile.d/configproxy.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp host "itworks"
```

Comment: Do the active directory users have `bash` or another Bourne compatible shell such as `sh`, `ksh`, or `ash` as their login shell?

Comment: @NasirRiley They log with the ubuntu gui so I guess they don't have a login shell. I don't know if I understand your question well.

Comment: Every user has a shell whether they are a local user or an LDAP user such as AD. You can see your shell when you log in with your AD account with the command `echo $0`. You can also see it in AD in the user's profile in the tab `Unix Attributes`. Add the shell to the question.

Comment: What happens when, as a test, you change your configuration to invoke your shell as `/bin/bash` rather than `/bin/kwartz.sh`?

Comment: @SottoVoce I'm not sure, I know how to do that.

Comment: I hadn't realized your computer didn't already have `/bin/bash` and you had to simulate it by linking it to `/bin/kwartz-sh`.  I think you may have to find out from this person Kwartz what shell features are supported by this shell.